# Whatever happened to adding a 'shopping request' close reason?

Tags: feature-request

Came here to ask why there's no close reason to deal with tool and service requests.

Found it'd already been asked.

[Do we need to add an additional close reason for Shopping Request questions?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/do-we-need-to-add-an-additional-close-reason-for-shopping-request-questions/1692#1692)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I still believe it would be useful on this site, it's not really something that has enough necessitity for it to be enabled here.

I've posted about it on the main [Stack Exchange Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206936/should-shopping-request-be-a-default-close-reason-for-all-stack-exchange-sites) and general opinion was that "Primarily opinion-based' is a close reason that generally encapsulates that issue.

In order to set up a specific one for Shopping Requests we would have to sacrifice one of the three custom ones we already have:

> Questions about **Implementation** are off-topic because this site is for User Experience design questions, not questions around how to implement these designs. Therefore, questions around the use of programs like Photoshop or languages such as CSS or JavaScript are off topic.
>
> Questions about **Site Reviews** are off-topic because questions here are expected to be relevant for a variety of people in the same situation. Reviewing a site, flow or interface only helps one person at a specific time. Instead try to ask a focused question about a particular aspect of the design that solicits solutions, not opinions.
>
> Questions requesting **Icon Suggestions** are off topic. While the subject of icons is on topic, there's very little value in soliciting suggestions for a specific icon in a specific context. See this meta post for more information about this topic.

And these closures get used pretty often and can't really be sacrificed when the 'Primarily Opinion-Based' closure will probably suffice.